# Git push - fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor

Tags: git, push

I'm new to Git, so please forgive me if this is a stupid question.

On my initial push to GitHub, using `git push origin master`

I'm getting the following error(s):

```
Counting objects: 1499, done. Delta compression using up to 16 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1455/1455), done. 
error: pack-objects died of signal 923 MiB | 9.10 MiB/s    fatal:
The remote end hung up unexpectedly fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: write error: Bad file descriptor
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Maybe the remote hard drive disk is full?

Comment: Would that effect a push to GitHub?

Comment: Your right, on github, you shouldn't have this kind of problem... Your kind of problem is analysed [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/github/comments/3apryd/trying_to_push_to_a_repo_but_getting_this_error/), and a possibly solution is [here](http://www.webbykat.com/2012/02/installing-git-solving-fatal-unable-create-thread-resource-temporarily-unavailable-problem)

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately that doesn't seem to have solved the problem. But thanks for the resources!

Answer (score 16):

When I got this same error, the following command fixed this issue
`git config --global pack.windowMemory "32m"`.

Comment: Thanks very much. I still get the same issue, but thanks for your help none the less!

Answer (score 3):

I was getting same error few days back what worked for me was that default file post size for Git has been exceeded.So navigate to repo and run this command to increase the buffer to 500MB after navigating to the repository `git config http.postBuffer 524288000`

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried it, and it still returns the same error.
I'm not sure what's going wrong, to know how to fix it.